# $\newcommand{\b}[1]{\langle#1\rangle}$Is the expectation of an operator written as $\b{\psi|\hat A|\psi}$ or as $\b{\psi|\hat A|\psi}/\b{\psi|\psi}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, normalization

I had presumed that the expectation of an operator is written as $\b{\hat A} = \b{\psi|\hat A|\psi}$, but some online reference insists on dividing the entire expression by $\b{\psi|\psi}$. Since $\b{\psi|\psi}$ is just one what is the point?

Comment: The title and body seem to be asking different questions. Also: Dirac notation LaTeX tip: Use \langle and \rangle ($\langle \cdot \rangle$) instead of < and > ($<\cdot >$).

Answer (score 4):

We divide by the norm of $\left|\psi\right>$ in order to take into account the case where the vector is not normalised.

If $\langle \psi|\psi\rangle=1$ it makes no difference and if it's not, you recover the correct result as well.

Answer (score 2):

When it's written with an extra division of $<\psi|\psi>$, it is just that $|\psi>$ is not normalized.